# react native graphql-tag TypeError: Object is not a function (near '...(0, _graphqlTag.default)...')

Tags: react-native, graphql-tag

this is how am importing gql in my app

`import gql from "graphql-tag";`

but still am getting this error

```
[Sun Jun 06 2021 15:12:57.243]  ERROR    TypeError: Object is not a function (near '...(0, _graphqlTag.default)...')
[Sun Jun 06 2021 15:12:57.243]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
[Sun Jun 06 2021 15:12:57.244]  ERROR    Invariant Violation: Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imW6j.png)

Comment: try this: `import { gql } from 'apollo-boost'`

Comment: already tried importing from apollo boost and it says ```TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '...(0, _apolloBoost.gql)...')```